# Replace the decimal mark produced by the numeric keypad with a comma in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to use the numeric keypad in the keyboard to enter numbers. My spreadsheet is in the French locale and uses comma `,` for decimal mark instead of a period `.`. Problem is that the <kbd>.</kbd> key in the numeric keypad gives a period rather than a comma.

The end result is that decimal numbers entered with the numeric keypad turn into text strings like this:

`1234.56`

...when I would need them to be numbers like this:

`1234,56`

I cannot change the global language or keyboard settings because I am using US number and date formats everywhere else, including in other Google Sheets.

How can I use the numeric keypad to enter decimal numbers in a particular Google Sheet?

Comment: In response to [Google sheet transformé . et ,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69652272/13045193).

Comment: Just switch your os language to french when you need to enter french numbers, it's so obvious

Comment: I cannot change the global language or keyboard settings because I am using US number and date formats everywhere else, including in other Google Sheets.

Comment: Isn't the  original question saying something opposite? `.replace(',','.')` in the original code.

Comment: Indeed it is, based on the incorrect assumption that the decimal mark would be part of the _value_, when it is just part of the _number format_. The attempted solution in the original question treats values as text strings and sets the value to a text string rather than a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that finds if the entered value is a text string that looks like `0000.00`, and converts it to a number if that is the case, like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* For use with Google Sheets in international locales that use comma as decimal mark.
* Converts text strings that look like numbers with period as decimal mark to numbers.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e || !e.value || Number.isNaN(Number(e.value))) {
    return;
  }
  if (e.value.match(/^\d*\.\d+$/) && typeof e.range.getValue() === 'string') {
    e.range.setValue(Number(e.value));
  }
}
```

**Edit 2023-02-11**

For posterity: Google Sheets now supports [locale-specific keyboard mappings with numeric keypads](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/02/expanding-power-of-google-sheets.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows there is the alternative solution. You can use [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and try this script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive French
NumpadDot::.
```

It will change the <kbd>NumpadDot</kbd> to <kbd>.</kbd> for every window (browser tabs included) which window title contains the word 'French'.

- https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm
- https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm